# Retrieve Mobile Device Report via Google Reports API via google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I am trying to retrieve the mobile device report but I keep getting this error: "API call to directory.mobiledevices.list failed with error: Bad Request".

I think the issue is the customerId. What should I use to retrieve all mobile devices info? I have tried using "all" and also defining the domain name but no luck.

Must appreciated for your time and input! TIA!

```
function mobileReport() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  sheet.clear();

  // Append the headers.
  var headers = ['Full Name','Email','Device Id','Model','Type','Status','Last Sync'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers).setFrozenRows(1);

  var rows = [];
  var pageToken;
  var count = 0;

  do {
    var page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list({
     orderBy: 'email',
     maxResults: 500,
     pageToken: pageToken    
    });
    var users = page.mobiledevices;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];           
        rows.push([user.name,user.email,user.deviceId,user.model,user.type,user.status,user.lastSync]);
      }
      // Append the results.
      sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length,headers.length).setValues(rows);
    } 
    else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  } 
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw [the official document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/list), it seems that at the method of "Method: mobiledevices.list" in Directory API, `customerId` is required to be used as follows.

  > `customerId`: The unique ID for the customer's Google Workspace account. As an account administrator, you can also use the my_customer alias to represent your account's customerId. The customerId is also returned as part of the [Users resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users).

  - But in your script, this is not used. By this, the arguments for `AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list` are not correct. I think that this is the reason of your issue of "Bad Request".
- The maximum value of `maxResults` is `100`.
- It seems that the email of Enum of `orderBy` is `EMAIL`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/list#OrderBy)
- In your script, `setValues` is used in the loop and the same range is used. In this case, the values are overwritten by every loop.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var rows = [];
var pageToken;
var count = 0;

do {
  var page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list({
   orderBy: 'email',
   maxResults: 500,
   pageToken: pageToken    
  });
  var users = page.mobiledevices;
  if (users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];           
      rows.push([user.name,user.email,user.deviceId,user.model,user.type,user.status,user.lastSync]);
    }
    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length,headers.length).setValues(rows);
  } 
  else {
  Logger.log('No users found.');
} 
  pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
```

To:

```
var customerId = "###"; // <--- Please set customerId.

var rows = [];
var pageToken;
var count = 0;  // It seems that this variable is not used in the script.
do {
  var page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list(customerId, {
    orderBy: 'EMAIL',
    maxResults: 100,
    pageToken: pageToken
  });
  var users = page.mobiledevices;
  if (users.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];
      rows.push([user.name, user.email, user.deviceId, user.model, user.type, user.status, user.lastSync]);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
  pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
if (rows.length > 0) {
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you can retrieve the values using `AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list`. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: mobiledevices.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/list)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! I read the doc and I must have missed read this "To retrieve all of an account's mobile devices", you are correct. It does need the customerId. Perhaps I need to use the reports under the Audit log>Devices. I think this is new and will look into this. Your input above will help in the future should I need to grab information for an individual account.

Comment: @JMMR... Thank you for replying.